# Java empty array

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Currently I'm trying to receive information from a mysql database with the Volley libary (with http request). But when I want to display the information in my android app I receive lots of errors.

> 10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.jamie.fysio, PID: 11718
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jamie.fysio.Home.showJSON(Home.java:79)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jamie.fysio.Home.access$000(Home.java:28)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jamie.fysio.Home$1.onResponse(Home.java:55)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jamie.fysio.Home$1.onResponse(Home.java:52)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   10-07 20:51:27.205 11718-11718/com.example.jamie.fysio E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

This is my method for parsing the JSON:

```
public class parseJSON {
    public static String[] adres;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    public static final String ADRES = "adres";

    private JSONArray users = null;

    private String json;


    public parseJSON(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSONMeth(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            adres = new String[users.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                adres[i] = jo.getString(ADRES);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my sendrequest :

```
private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(KEY_USERNAME, gebruikersnaam);
        return map;
    }
};

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json) {
    parseJSON pj = new parseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSONMeth();
    adres.setText(parseJSON.adres[0]);
}
```

}

I"m not very familiar with the volley libary what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to debug `parseJSONMeth` and check if it is executing correctly. Your crash is happening because `parseJson` seems to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `response` you get from the `onResponse(String response)` doesn't seem to pass a valid `JSONObject` which leads to a `JSONException` being caught before `adres` is assigned.

Check your `JSON_URL`.

By the way `adres` shouldn't be static, and should be accessed through `pj`.

Comment: Looks like that his app has NPE, not JSONException :)

Comment: @BNK Yes, as I said the `JSONException` is caught, so `adres` couldn't be assigned so `adres` is null at `adres[0]`, thus a NPE.